# Crash when trying to paint on loaded QPixMap image

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on a project that is basically Paint. I implemented opening file feature, so when I open file it loads into QPixmap.

**The problem is**: when I try to draw on successfully loaded QPixmap, my application **crashes**(no error or something, it just closes itself). I will provide my code for drawing and opening file. I think the rest(UI and etc.) isn't neccessary in this case.

Drawing:

```
class Canvas(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.white)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.myPixmap = QPixmap(600, 600)
        self.painter = QPainter(self.myPixmap)
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
        self.painter.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600, Qt.white)
        self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)
        self.last = None    

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.last:
            self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
            self.painter.drawLine(self.last, event.pos())

            self.last = event.pos()
            self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.last = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.last = None
```

Opening file:

```
def openFile(self):
    openFile_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File:', '', 'Images (*.png *.bmp *.jpg)')
    openFile_ok = self.canvas.myPixmap.load(openFile_file[0])
    self.canvas.setPixmap(self.canvas.myPixmap)
    self.canvas.update()
    print('open', openFile_ok)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two main problems were 1) not ending the painting done in construction and 2) not resetting the painter after loading new image.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QFileDialog

class Canvas(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), Qt.white)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(p)
        self.myPixmap = QPixmap(600, 600)
        self.painter = QPainter(self.myPixmap)
        self.pen = QPen()
        self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
        self.painter.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600, Qt.white)
        self.painter.end()  # Need to end the painting here
        self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)

        self.last = None
        self.image_loaded = False

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.last:
            self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
            self.painter.drawLine(self.last, event.pos())

            self.last = event.pos()
            self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)
            self.update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.image_loaded:
            self.openFile()
            self.image_loaded = True
        self.last = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.last = None

    def openFile(self):
        openFile_file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File:', '', 'Images (*.png *.bmp *.jpg)')
        openFile_ok = self.myPixmap.load(openFile_file[0])
        self.setPixmap(self.myPixmap)

        self.painter = QPainter(self.myPixmap)  # Need to reset the painter...there may be another method without creating a new painter
        self.painter.setPen(self.pen)

        self.update()
        print('open', openFile_ok)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = Canvas()
label.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```